# Essential singularity of e^{1/z}, function takes every value

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

The function $e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity in $0$ an takes every non-zero value in every neighborhood of $0$. This follows from the Picard theorem. The question is: how can we prove this without the Picard, only with Casorati-Weierstraß and open mapping theorem? Does somebody have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: $e^{\frac{1}{z}}=x+iy\rightarrow \frac{1}{z}=\ln(x+iy)+2k\pi i\rightarrow z=\frac{1}{\ln(x+iy)+2k\pi i}$. If you take $k$ high enough, this expression is arbitrarily near $0$, and takes value $x+iy$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!